# Logcat not updating for only some code

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to create an app and got stuck at a place. To debug, I have added Log.d messages.
However, I am not getting the log outputs for a certain part of the code. I am getting the log outputs for other parts.
This is weird but is there any solution for it?

PS: There are no filtering enabled, the device is correctly pointed.

```
08-16 00:09:16.102: W/SoundPool(87):   sample 0 not READY
08-16 00:09:16.132: D/PhoneStatusBar(139): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK HOME recent* CLOCK >
08-16 00:09:16.542: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009002_00000000 [127 ipp] (149 ins) at [0x4119e818:0x4119ea6c] in 2714369 ns
08-16 00:09:16.662: D/PhoneStatusBar(139): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back* home* recent clock* >
08-16 00:09:16.752: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009001_00000000 [131 ipp] (153 ins) at [0x4119ea70:0x4119ecd4] in 856742 ns

/**********************************
/**Log msgs shd have started here
/**********************************/

08-16 00:09:40.572: W/ThrottleService(87): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
08-16 00:09:59.873: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1913K, 24% free 10314K/13447K, paused 29ms+4ms
08-16 00:10:00.323: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 22% free 10504K/13447K, paused 51ms+11ms
08-16 00:10:01.943: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 617K, 23% free 10395K/13447K, paused 12ms+5ms
08-16 00:10:02.253: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 255K, 21% free 10649K/13447K, paused 12ms+6ms
08-16 00:10:02.483: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 20% free 10873K/13447K, paused 12ms+6ms
08-16 00:10:02.633: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 17% free 11247K/13447K, paused 61ms
08-16 00:10:20.513: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1633K, 24% free 10332K/13447K, paused 12ms+6ms
08-16 00:10:20.793: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 220K, 22% free 10548K/13447K, paused 11ms+7ms
08-16 00:10:47.174: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(524): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
08-16 00:10:47.174: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(524):   in Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl) {4138f060}
08-16 00:10:47.174: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(524):   0: sent at 193445000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=158, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=193445, downTime=193341, deviceId=0, source=0x301 }
08-16 00:10:50.823: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 21% free 10636K/13447K, paused 6ms+22ms
08-16 00:10:51.433: W/WindowManager(87): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21020
08-16 00:10:51.832: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(87): setKernelCountSet(10013, 1) failed with errno -2
08-16 00:10:52.332: I/Process(87): Sending signal. PID: 184 SIG: 3
08-16 00:10:52.342: I/dalvikvm(184): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-16 00:10:52.393: W/InputManagerService(87): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415ebf40 (uid=10040 pid=524)
08-16 00:10:52.482: I/dalvikvm(184): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-16 00:10:52.752: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009004_00000000 [122 ipp] (142 ins) at [0x4119ecd8:0x4119ef10] in 968806 ns
08-16 00:10:52.902: I/dalvikvm(87): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
08-16 00:10:53.312: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(87): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2
08-16 00:10:53.442: D/dalvikvm(524): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1214K, 29% free 9573K/13447K, paused 4ms+7ms
```

Comment: maybe the code is not executing. put a toast message where you are tryin to log. Toast messages are usually foolproof

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the current logcat has this error. Did you update the android sdk Tools and android sdk platform-tools ? If this error continue after updated, you can use the logcat deprecated or try to restart your IDE.

Comment: Thanks I realised it was an issue with my code and no setup issue.